# Crop image in PHP

Tags: php, gd, crop

The code below crops the image well, which is what i want, but for larger images, it wotn work as well. Is there any way of 'zooming out of the image'

Idealy i would be able to have each image roughly the same size before cropping so that i would get good results each time

Code is

```
<?php

$image = $_GET['src']; // the image to crop
$dest_image = 'images/cropped_whatever.jpg'; // make sure the directory is writeable

$img = imagecreatetruecolor('200','150');
$org_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$ims = getimagesize($image);
imagecopy($img,$org_img, 0, 0, 20, 20, 200, 150);
imagejpeg($img,$dest_image,90);
imagedestroy($img);
echo '<img src="'.$dest_image.'" ><p>';
```

Comment: Are you trying to create thumbnails?

Comment: yes i am trying to create thumbnails

Comment: For such tasks you should consider using a library. I recommend [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/). For instance, see these methods: [`resize()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize), [`fit()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit).

Comment: explain `($img,$org_img, 0, 0, 20, 20, 200, 150)`.  Replacing `src` with my file name (weather.jpg) failed.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you are trying to generate thumbnails, you must first resize the image using `imagecopyresampled();`. You must resize the image so that the size of the smaller side of the image is equal to the corresponding side of the thumb.

For example, if your source image is 1280x800px and your thumb is 200x150px, you must resize your image to 240x150px and then crop it to 200x150px. This is so that the aspect ratio of the image won't change.

Here's a general formula for creating thumbnails:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
$filename = 'images/cropped_whatever.jpg';

$thumb_width = 200;
$thumb_height = 150;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
   // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
   $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                   0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);
```

Haven't tested this but it *should* work.

**EDIT**

Now tested and working.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but its not working, i cant see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Got it to work kind of

http://t-webdesign.co.uk/crop.php?src=http://extreme-showcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/whitetubes12.JPG

But its not working well vertically, any help?

Comment: Thanks, still not giving the right results tho see above link , thankssss

Comment: Okay, maybe I should test it myself first.. Gimme a sec and I'll post a fixed version.

Comment: Nice work :)  can we make this script to crop any format images like png, gif ?

Comment: Just replace `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);` with `$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_GET['src']));`.

Comment: This piece of code saved me countless hours, or probably days. Thanks a lot. I modified it according to my requirement, but basics remain the same.

Comment: What is difference between scale then crop v/s crop then scale? Will the results differ?

Comment: Thanks! can I use it freely? or you require to give credit, as SO terms state?

Comment: This code is missing `imagedestroy` on `$image` and `$thumb`. It will work fine once, but if you take this code and put it in a loop it will be hitting the memory limit.

Answer (score 17):

`imagecopyresampled()` will take a rectangular area from `$src_image` of width `$src_w` and height `$src_h` at position `($src_x, $src_y)` and place it in a rectangular area of `$dst_image` of width `$dst_w` and height `$dst_h` at position `($dst_x, $dst_y)`.

If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed. The coordinates refer to the upper left corner.

This function can be used to copy regions within the same image. But if the regions overlap, the results will be unpredictable.

### - Edit -

If `$src_w` and `$src_h` are smaller than `$dst_w` and `$dst_h` respectively, thumb image will be zoomed in. Otherwise it will be zoomed out.

```
<?php
$dst_x = 0;   // X-coordinate of destination point
$dst_y = 0;   // Y-coordinate of destination point
$src_x = 100; // Crop Start X position in original image
$src_y = 100; // Crop Srart Y position in original image
$dst_w = 160; // Thumb width
$dst_h = 120; // Thumb height
$src_w = 260; // Crop end X position in original image
$src_h = 220; // Crop end Y position in original image

// Creating an image with true colors having thumb dimensions (to merge with the original image)
$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
// Get original image
$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/source.jpg');
// Cropping
imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
// Saving
imagejpeg($dst_image, 'images/crop.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: While a code only answer might work, it is best if the answer at least contains a little explanation of how it works, so that folks can understand the code without having to read and mentally interpret each line of code.

Answer (score 4):

php 5.5 has an imagecrop function http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
```

Needs to be replaced with this:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/thumbnails/myimage.jpg');
```

Because `imagecreatefromjpeg()` is expecting a string.
This worked for me.

***ref:***
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:-

```
enter code here
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="image" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

upload.php

```
enter code here
<?php 
      $image = $_FILES;
      $NewImageName = rand(4,10000)."-". $image['image']['name'];
      $destination = realpath('../images/testing').'/';
      move_uploaded_file($image['image']['tmp_name'], $destination.$NewImageName);
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($destination.$NewImageName);
      $filename = $destination.$NewImageName;

      $thumb_width = 200;
      $thumb_height = 150;

      $width = imagesx($image);
      $height = imagesy($image);

      $original_aspect = $width / $height;
      $thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

      if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
      {
         // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
         $new_height = $thumb_height;
         $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
      }
      else
      {
         // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
         $new_width = $thumb_width;
         $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
      }

      $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

      // Resize and crop
      imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                         $image,
                         0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                         0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                         0, 0,
                         $new_width, $new_height,
                         $width, $height);
      imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 80);
      echo "cropped"; die;
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved Crop image functionality in PHP on the fly.

```
http://www.example.com/cropimage.php?filename=a.jpg&newxsize=100&newysize=200&constrain=1
```

Code in `cropimage.php`

```
$basefilename = @basename(urldecode($_REQUEST['filename']));

$path = 'images/';
$outPath = 'crop_images/';
$saveOutput = false; // true/false ("true" if you want to save images in out put folder)
$defaultImage = 'no_img.png'; // change it with your default image

$basefilename = $basefilename;
$w = $_REQUEST['newxsize'];
$h = $_REQUEST['newysize'];

if ($basefilename == "") {
    $img = $path . $defaultImage;
    $percent = 100;
} else {
    $img = $path . $basefilename;

    $len = strlen($img);
    $ext = substr($img, $len - 3, $len);
    $img2 = substr($img, 0, $len - 3) . strtoupper($ext);
    if (!file_exists($img)) $img = $img2;
    if (file_exists($img)) {
        $percent = @$_GET['percent'];
        $constrain = @$_GET['constrain'];
        $w = $w;
        $h = $h;
    } else if (file_exists($path . $basefilename)) {
        $img = $path . $basefilename;
        $percent = $_GET['percent'];
        $constrain = $_GET['constrain'];
        $w = $w;
        $h = $h;
    } else {

        $img = $path . 'no_img.png';    // change with your default image
        $percent = @$_GET['percent'];
        $constrain = @$_GET['constrain'];
        $w = $w;
        $h = $h;

    }

}

// get image size of img
$x = @getimagesize($img);

// image width
$sw = $x[0];
// image height
$sh = $x[1];

if ($percent > 0) {
    // calculate resized height and width if percent is defined
    $percent = $percent * 0.01;
    $w = $sw * $percent;
    $h = $sh * $percent;
} else {
    if (isset ($w) AND !isset ($h)) {
        // autocompute height if only width is set
        $h = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
        $h = @round($sh * $h);
    } elseif (isset ($h) AND !isset ($w)) {
        // autocompute width if only height is set
        $w = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
        $w = @round($sw * $w);
    } elseif (isset ($h) AND isset ($w) AND isset ($constrain)) {
        // get the smaller resulting image dimension if both height
        // and width are set and $constrain is also set
        $hx = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
        $hx = @round($sh * $hx);

        $wx = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
        $wx = @round($sw * $wx);

        if ($hx < $h) {
            $h = (100 / ($sw / $w)) * .01;
            $h = @round($sh * $h);
        } else {
            $w = (100 / ($sh / $h)) * .01;
            $w = @round($sw * $w);
        }
    }
}

$im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG($img) or // Read JPEG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromPNG($img) or // or PNG Image
$im = @ImageCreateFromGIF($img) or // or GIF Image
$im = false; // If image is not JPEG, PNG, or GIF

if (!$im) {
    // We get errors from PHP's ImageCreate functions...
    // So let's echo back the contents of the actual image.
    readfile($img);
} else {
    // Create the resized image destination
    $thumb = @ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);
    // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
    @ImageCopyResampled($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $sw, $sh);

    //Other format imagepng()

    if ($saveOutput) { //Save image
        $save = $outPath . $basefilename;
        @ImageJPEG($thumb, $save);
    } else { // Output resized image
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        @ImageJPEG($thumb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`imagecrop`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php) function in (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

Example:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('example.png');
$size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
    imagepng($im2, 'example-cropped.png');
    imagedestroy($im2);
}
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
$filename = 'images/cropped_whatever.jpg'
```

Must be replaced with:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);
```

Then it will work!