# How to crop and resize an image file for a profile picture

Tags: php, profile, image, crop

I'm making a site and I need all the users to have a square profile picture. Could anyone point me to a site that explains the process of cropping an image/resizing image with php?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my simple image manipulation class - https://gist.github.com/880506

It provides basic cropping, resampling and canvas resizing.

You can use it as-is or treat it as a learning source.

Answer (score 0):

first you can get that image width and height with `getimagesize()`
and create an imagestring with `file_get_contents()`
and create a source for your profile image with width and height that you need
and create $tmp with `imagecreatetrueclor()`
at the latest you create an image for profile whit `imagejpg()`
the next step you should empty the memory with `imagedestroy()`