# Image Resizing and Crop to fit in Frame

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I am trying to build a PHP library that will resize an image down to a specific size, but am coming across a few issues which I can't quite work out.

I am trying to make it so that it will resize and crop an image in the following way (all scaling is kept to the aspect ratio of the image):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php

Comment: @JordanRichards possibly, gonna try with that and if it works, sorted :D

Comment: That's all well and good but, next time before you post a question, make sure that question has not already been asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JordanRichards I did have a look, but my focus was on titles around resizing, not just cropping

Comment: no problem. Now remember what I said, remember to check for the question already on SOF incase you make a duplicate. Anyway, at least you've learnt a lesson.

Comment: Here is how we do it in c#, check my answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014365/c-sharp-crop-image-from-center/27164374#27164374