# image crop with php

Tags: php

I want to crop `30px` from an image only from the bottom of it. I did some search and find some  stuff, but when I tried it and save the image, the image got saved all black and I am not sure even if the image got cropped. I don't want to go back to the code that I have right now. So what is the fastest and easiest way to crop an image ?

Comment: you didn't mentioned what piece of code you're using. 
Can you please explain what code in PHP or any other you're using?

Comment: do you want me to post the code I used ?

Comment: What type of image? What have you tried?

Comment: not necessary all the time, but you can mentioned what library or available code you've used.

If you want to show you code then don't paste in your question, please put it in pastebin.com and share link here.

Comment: png, jpg, and gif. ALl got saved black

Comment: Please check below link .

[Crop image in PHP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the image crop function of the image library in codeigniter `$this->image_lib->crop()`
but before using image functions make sure that you load the image library first
`$this->load->library('image_lib');`

you can find this in [docs here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html)