# Cropping image in php with 2 coordinates

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crop image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php)

How to crop a part of an image when i have the coordinates of the upper left corner and lower right corner? I can't use the imagecopyresampled function cause in only use the upper left corner as a staring point and the end of the rectangle is determined automatically not by the coordinates of the lower right corner . :(
Can anyone help? pls

Comment: you can use cropImage() is a php function

Comment: and how do i install ImageMagick ? for linux

Comment: what is your linux?[centos](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11664)

Comment: this is ImageMagick installing tutorial too [link](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=44449)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all [here's](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1709-cropping-images-using-php.html) a tutorial that was recommended to me for a similar problem.
If this doesn't help, your solution will be buried away in the GD library somewhere. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is the API for it. Hope that's of some use to you!

As Andrej correctly pointed out, [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is probably the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php

and there's a lot of examples.