# Resizing Image max-width and height

Tags: php, image, resize, png

I've been looking all over the internet to find the solution for this. I'm using this SimpleImage.php class to resize an image that I found here (http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php). So far everything works perfectly fine. If I try to re size the image to its specific height or width it is doing its job. However, this only works if I am trying to resize the image one at a time. Let's say the original size of my image is 1400x1100, and I want to resize its height to 800. This will give me a result of  **some numberx800**. And vice versa.

My goal is to resize the image according to the MAX-WIDTH AND MAX-HEIGHT that I am passing.

Something like this:

```
$image = new SimpleImage();
          $image->load($image_url); 
          $image->resizeToWidthHeight(MAX-WIDTH, MAX-HEIGHT);
          $image->save('photo.png');
```

Here is my SimpleImage.php Class

```
<?php
    class SimpleImage {
     var $image;
     var $image_type;

     function load($filename) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
        if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        }
    }
    function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
        if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            imagegif($this->image,$filename);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            imagepng($this->image,$filename);
        }
        if( $permissions != null) {
            chmod($filename,$permissions);
        }
    }

    function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            imagejpeg($this->image);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
            imagegif($this->image);
        } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            imageAlphaBlending($this->image, true);
            imageSaveAlpha($this->image, true);
            imagepng($this->image);
        }   
    }

    function getWidth() {
        return imagesx($this->image);
    }
    function getHeight() {
        return imagesy($this->image);
    }
    function resizeToHeight($height) {
        $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
        $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }
    function resizeToWidth($width) {
        $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
        $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }
    function scale($scale) {
        $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
        $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
        $this->resize($width,$height);
    }


    function resize($width,$height) {

        // ADDED CODE IS HERE - NOT SURE WHY IT DOESN'T WORK FOR PNG

        // Setup new image
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        // These parameters are required for handling PNG files.
        imagealphablending($new_image, false);
        imagesavealpha($new_image,true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
        // Resize image
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions of your image change: you go from 3:4 to 16:9, you need to apply some cropping somewhere.

Figure out which dimension is the smallest based on the scale, resize on that property and then crop the other dimension.

---

In my experience **scale is always wrong**. I suggest you remove it from the library. resize + crop is the way to go.

You could write a function a like `cropTo($newX, $newY)`

Comment: Do you have any other reference to assist me?

Comment: I think this is a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php