# Adjust the width and height dinamically Cloudinary

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, cloudinary

I am trying to integrate Cloudinary into my webpage. The problem is that when I use the code below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-center product-image">
    <?php 

    echo cl_image_tag($product['product_url'], 
        array("width"=>400, "height"=>300, "crop"=>"fill"));

    ?>
</div>
```

The image is not responsive due to the fixed proportions: `"width"=>400, "height"=>300`.

Is there a way of adjusting these parameters dynamically to the width and height that Bootstrap defines for the div?

I have tried this:

```
<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 300px;" src="<?php echo $product['product_url']; ?>">
```

But then the size of each image is different, because each one has different dimensions and aspect ratios.

Comment: Could you add more HTML code ?

Comment: sure, but What can I add? that div is not inside another div it's just inside the body and there is no other html element related to that one

Comment: What you mean by ` image is not responsive due to the fixed proportions`?

Comment: I mean that the image does not decrease it's size when I make the web browser smaller

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use class `.img-fluid` with max-width: 100%; and height: auto;`

This [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#responsive-images) may help

While using `.img-thumbnail` you should not use width and height

Here is the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#image-thumbnails)

Comment: Because I want all the images to be at max 400x300 but keep their aspect ratio original, so I need to crop the image. That's why I'm using cl_image_tag()

Comment: for cropping the image in php use the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php#answer-1856049`

Answer (score -1):

You could try add this to css:

```
.product-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But the images still 400x300 when I resize the window