# Featured image Wordpress - automatically scale up and hide placehold.it

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog that only acccepts featured images with the minimum size of 720 x 422 pixels. If I upload a image with smaller dimensions, it displays a placeholder (from placeholder.it) showing the minium sizes required.

I would like to know if it's possible to automatically scale up the featured image after upload it, even if it decreases the image quality, so the placeholder won't appear, but only the uploaded image.

Here's a example of the issue: http://www.vereverso.com.br/que-violencia-e-essa/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php) and [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220574/wordpress-hook-that-gets-featured-image-from-direct-url)

Answer (score 0):

write this in functions.php

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 750, 422 );
```